# Java create thread with parameters

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that counts several times a word in the text.
I want the loop to be in a separate thread. How can I pass parameters `articles` and `stringToSearch` to the thread, or set the global parameters?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberArticles = s.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < numberArticles; i++) {
            String articleName = s.nextLine();
            String content = ""; 
            File file = new File(articleName + ".txt"); 
              BufferedReader br;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                  String st; 
                  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    content += st; 
                  } 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            articles.add(new Article(articleName, content));
        }
        String stringToSearch = s.nextLine();
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();
    }
}
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        for(Article article : articles) {
            int counter = 0;
            String[] words = article.getContent().split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if(word.equals(stringToSearch)) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are extending `Thread` with your custom class. And you can add any number of any additional properties to that class (`MyThread`). And you can create a constructor in `MyThread` to pass all those parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example showing how to pass some values into the constructor for your `MyThread` class. This passes two things into the constructor which then saves them to private members which can then be used within the `run()` method. I removed most of the other code from your question since it wasn't required for this explanation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Scratch2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
        String stringToSearch = "...";

        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(articles, stringToSearch);
        myThread.start();
    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final ArrayList<Article> articles;
    private final String stringToSearch;

    public MyThread(ArrayList<Article> articles, String stringToSearch) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.stringToSearch = stringToSearch;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (Article article : articles) {
            // ... do things with "stringToSearch"
        }
    }
}

class Article {

    // more stuff here

}
```